# How to override webform in template.php

Tags: webforms, theming

I've followed different tutorials but I cannot seem to override a field on my webform via a function in template.php.

> Theme is called: 'myTheme'
>  Id of the form is:
>   'webform_client_form_76'
>  Id of the input:
>   'edit-submitted-henkilotiedot-etunimi'
>  Name of the input:
>   'submitted[henkilotiedot][etunimi]'

The function I think should work:

```
function myTheme_webform_form_76 (&$vars) {
    $vars['form']['submitted']['edit-submitted-henkilotiedot-etunimi']['#value'] = t('Name');
}
```

What is the correct format to override webform elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function [themename]_form_webform_client_form_76_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
// code of altering
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I seem to also have the format of the code to alter wrong as well: `$form['form']['submitted']['edit-submitted-henkilotiedot-etunimi']['#value'] = t('Name');`

Comment: Setup devel module and then use `kpr($form);` to research $form structure. Looks like it should be `$form['submitted']['henkilotiedot_etunimi']['#value'] = t('Name');`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It turns out I needed `$form['submitted']['henkilotiedot']['etunimi']['#default_value'] = t('Name');`